# constantly checking if time is 5:00 PM jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

```js
        function updateTime() {
          var m_names = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "March",
            "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept",
            "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
          var now = new Date();
          var date = now.getDate();
          var year = now.getFullYear();
          var month = now.getMonth();
          var currentHoursAP = now.getHours();
          var currentHours = now.getHours();
          var currentMinutes = now.getMinutes();
          var currentSeconds = now.getSeconds();
          // Pad the minutes and seconds with leading zeros, if required
          currentMinutes = (currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentMinutes;
          currentSeconds = (currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentSeconds;

          // Choose either "AM" or "PM" as appropriate
          var timeOfDay = (currentHours < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";

          // Convert the hours component to 12-hour format if needed
          currentHoursAP = (currentHours > 12) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;

          // Convert an hours component of "0" to "12"
          currentHoursAP = (currentHoursAP == 0) ? 12 : currentHoursAP;

          // Compose the string for display
          //var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + " / " + currentHoursAP + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;
          var currentTimeString = currentHoursAP + ":" + currentMinutes + " " + timeOfDay;



          //document.getElementById("TimeandDate").value = hour + ":" + minute + " " +"/" + " " + m_names[month] + " " + date + " " + year  ;
          $('#TimeandDate').html("Time:" + currentTimeString + "<br>Date:" + m_names[month] + "/" + date + "/" + year);
          //        $('#Time').text(currentTimeString);
          //        $('#Date').text(m_names[month] + "/" + date + "/" + year);
          return currentTimeString;
        }
        updateTime();
        setInterval(updateTime, 1000); // 5 * 1000 miliseconds





        console.log(updateTime())


        if ((updateTime() == '5:00 PM')) {
          alert(updateTime())
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="TimeandDate"></span>
```

I want to have a time checker in my project. I have a function that constantly updates time in a span. Now i want to keep checking if the time in the span is `5:00 PM` Because I need to show an alert. I tried returning the time in the function like having a

`return currentTimeString`

then using

```
if ((updateTime() == '5:00 PM')) {
   alert(updateTime())
}
```

> For testing purposes I change the time in if condition to nearest possible time but the alert is not showing.

Comment: your code that tests for 5:00PM is only run once, you need that test inside `updateTime()` to test correctly

Comment: is that the *"go have a beer"* alarm?

Comment: @JaromandaX i tried it but i get `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` 59 times i think 1 for every second. @ charlietfl more like **time to prepare dinner** :)

Comment: yeah, don't call updateTime() inside updateTIme to test for it being 5:00 PM ...

Comment: i added second to run the alert only ones because it is running 60 times you can give it as answer @JaromandaX i know it was pretty stupid question but you helped me so i need to provide the tick on answer

Comment: @JaromandaX will this slow the process `function updateTime() {  .... var currentTimeString1 = currentHoursAP + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;if ((currentTimeString1 == '11:29:00 AM')) {
            confirmor(currentTimeString1)
        }}function confirmor(currentTimeString1) {
        console.log(currentTimeString1)
    }`

Comment: not sure what "slow the process" means in this context

Comment: @JaromandaX i mean it will make the response of the page slow.

Comment: as far as I can tell, it shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code that tests for 5:00PM is only run once, you need that test inside updateTime() to test correctly

e.g.

```
function updateTime() {
    // ... code removed for clarity
    var currentTimeString = currentHoursAP + ":" + currentMinutes + " " + timeOfDay;
    // ... code removed for clarity
    if ((currentTimeString == '5:00 PM')) {
        alert("It's 5:00 PM")
    }
}
updateTime();
setInterval(updateTime, 1000); // 5 * 1000 miliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function isTriggerTime(hour, minute) {
  var now = new Date();
  return (now.getHours() === hour) && (now.getMinutes() === minute);
}

setInterval(function() {
  if(isTriggerTime(17, 0)) {
    alert('it is time');
  }
}, 400);
```